# Can't access control in footer of ASP.Net Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

By company mandate. I have a Gridview with a footertemplate, and in that template I have a textbox.

When I go to access it in code behind, it's coming up not found. Is this some kind of scope issue? Shouldn't the code behind have access to all the fields in my gridview?

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox Name="txtID" ControlID="cntID" Width="20" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</FooterTemplate>
```

.

```
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtID not found .....
```

Comment: What is the *actual* error message?

Comment: Could you please fix your tags? This is clearly not [tag:asp-classic].

Comment: with the coming of `asp.net mvc` so many are referring to `webforms` as classic. hmm :)

Comment: classic means the original active server pages, before even webforms

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: yeah. I was pointing out that mf web forms as classic nowadays :)any think

Answer (score 1):

When you nest one control inside another, it's best to use the parent control's [`FindControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Also, you need to give the control an ID attribute, not just a name.

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" ControlID="cntID" Width="20" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</FooterTemplate>
```

.

```
insert.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 50).Value = Gridview1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtID").Text
```

And if you're curious, here's [why I switched this away from AddWithValue()](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: you would need to typecast the control to TextBox too

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was thinking the Text property was part of the base Control type, but that's for Windows Forms, not Web Forms. I'll leave the answer as-is, though, because it's not clear from the question whether this is VB or C#, and the format for the cast changes significantly between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `ID` to your `textbox`, you cannot access contorls by `Name` in code behind.

```
asp:TextBox  ID="txtID" ControlID="cntID" Width="20" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```